# How see content column selecting with cursor

Tags: javafx, tableview, selecteditem

I need to know how I can view the contents of a cell depending on which is selected. I have to return the value of idPerson with method btnClick.

Thus goes the memory address but I want to return the id value I have selected

Thanks.

```
public class TablaFXML {
@FXML
TableView tablePeople;
@FXML
TableColumn idPersonColumn;
@FXML
TableColumn nameColumn;
@FXML
TableColumn surnameColumn;
@FXML
TableColumn emailColumn;
@FXML
TextArea textArea;
@FXML
Person pers;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(

    new Person("1", "Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),

    new Person("2", "Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),

    new Person("3", "Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),

    new Person("4", "Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),

    new Person("5", "Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")

    );

    idPersonColumn
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("idPerson"));
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));
    surnameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("surname"));
    emailColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("email"));

    tablePeople.setItems(data);

}

@FXML public void btnIdClick(){

    //int guardar = tablePeople.getSelectionModel().getFocusedIndex();


    System.out.println(tablePeople.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

}
```

}

```
public class Person {

private StringProperty idPerson;
private StringProperty name;
private StringProperty surname;
private StringProperty email;



public Person(String id,String fName, String lName, String email) {

    this.idPerson = new SimpleStringProperty(id);
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
    this.surname = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
    this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);

}



public StringProperty idPersonProperty() { return idPerson; }
public StringProperty nameProperty() { return name; }
public StringProperty surnameProperty() { return surname; }
public StringProperty emailProperty() { return email; }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the results of calling the `toString()` method on the `Person` object returned from the selection model. As you haven't overridden the `toString()` method, you are getting the result of the [default `toString` method defined in `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), which displays the class name and `hashCode`.

You can either add a `toString` method to the `Person` class:

```
public class Person {

    // ... all code as before

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.get() + " " + surname.get(); // any implementation you need
    }
}
```

or just extract the data you need when you need it:

```
@FXML public void btnIdClick() {
    Person selectedPerson = tablePeople.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() ;
    System.out.println(selectedPerson.firstNameProperty().get() + " " +
        selectedPerson.lastNameProperty().get());
}
```